# my App Store is broken for Mac High Sierra 10.13.5

Tags: mac-appstore, macos

[image: i will click featured or something else and it doesn't work]

I will click featured or something else and it automatically redirects me to updates.

What sequence of things can I try to unstick this or reset the application so I can browse the features and other sections of the Mac App Store?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by omitting the AppStore and installing all system updates through the terminal.

Open Terminal and type:

- List all available updates:

`sudo softwareupdate -l`

- Install all available updates:

`sudo softwareupdate -i -a`

This update fixes the app and returns proper function.

Comment: After doing this does it fix the issue? Also if this is a workaround, how would you buy anything new?

Comment: @bmike When you do this, the Appstore goes back to normal work. It is a bug in the latest versions of High Sierra

Comment: Thanks! I’ve made that explicit in the answer.

Comment: i have the lastest version of High Sierra and I don't have this problem.